# How do you filter arithmetic procedures in Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

I've beetn trying to filter specific procedures using a "cond" clause to no avail so far.

Here's an example of what I'd like my program to do:

```
(define (test procedure)
  (case procedure
    [#<procedure:+> "It's a sum"]
    [#<procedure:/> "It's a division"]
    [#<procedure:*> "It's a product"]
    ...
```

But so far, it ain't working, no matter how I tweak it.

Do you guys know what's the right way to filter specific procedures in Racket?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not using `cond`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't reference procedures using the `#` syntax, that's just used for output.

You can simply compare the parameter with the procedures using `eq?`:

```
(define (test procedure)
  (cond
    [(eq? procedure +) "It's a sum"]
    [(eq? procedure /) "It's a division"]
    ...))
```